# When opening .csv file in pandas read_csv file, shows all the columns in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in python and my problem is only opening a **file from my pc**: Pandas shows me all the columns in one in the data frame. When I try to open the same file from a URL, I have no problem with the data frame output.
For example this are the first lines on the file:

```
carat,cut,color,clarity,depth,table,price,x,y,z
 0.23,Ideal,E,SI2,61.5,55.0,326,3.95,3.98,2.43
```

I am using:

```
import pandas as pd

diam = pd.read_csv('C:\\analyst\\Diamonds.csv', sep=',')

diam
```

output:

```
carat,cut,color,clarity,depth,table,price,x,y,z
0   0.23,Ideal,E,SI2,61.5,55.0,326,3.95,3.98,2.43
1   0.21,Premium,E,SI1,59.8,61.0,326,3.89,3.84,2.31
2   0.23,Good,E,VS1,56.9,65.0,327,4.05,4.07,2.31
3   0.29,Premium,I,VS2,62.4,58.0,334,4.2,4.23,2.63
4   0.31,Good,J,SI2,63.3,58.0,335,4.34,4.35,2.75
... ...
```

I thought may be there is a problem with the Windows settings but I checked and everything is ok: for Decimal Symbol--> dot:.
for List Separator--> a comma:,

How I can get all columns in the data frame?

Comment: Can you share file to gdocs, wetransfrom, dropbox... ? Because it is data related problem.

Comment: You may use 
newData = diam.fillna("") and 
for row in newData.values.tolist():

Comment: no problem sharing file

Comment: Using-  newData = diam.fillna("") and for row in newData.values.tolist()

Comment: I got syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
diam = pd.read_csv('C:\\analyst\\Diamonds.csv', sep=',', names= ['carat','cut','color','clarity','depth','table','price','x','y','z'])
```

Comment: I obteined different columns but all the data still in column 1 ('carat')

Comment: I just downloaded diamonds.csv file from kaggle and tried it, both diam = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\atala\diamonds.csv", sep=',') and diam = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\atala\diamonds.csv", sep=',', names= ['carat','cut','color','clarity','depth','table','price','x','y','z'])
 work fine on my Windows computer.

Comment: Yes. The problem is not in the syntax. It is surely a problem with the data or in the reading of the files on my Windows 10 computer. Anyway thank you very much for your answer